Box-Cox Transformation and t-test
I have two datasets which I wish to test for difference of means (T-test). They are however not normally distributed, according to the Shapiro-test in R.
I have seen that Box-Cox transformation is the way to go, but do I use the same $\lambda$ to transform the data sets or do I transform them individually?
i.e:
$$y_{i,\,transformed} = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{y_i^\lambda-1}{\lambda} & \lambda\neq 0 \\
      \ln(y_i) & \lambda = 0 
   \end{cases}$$
Using one $\lambda$ for both dataset A and dataset B, or two $\lambda$'s ($\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$)?
Cheers

I think either is a possibility. Can you give us a little more context, e.g. edit your question to include some information about sample size and possibly histograms of each group? Depending on your sample size, the t-test may still be quite reliable even though the Shapiro-Wilk test rejects the null hypothesis of normality ...

Using different values of $\lambda$ would result in a numerical comparison of two incommensurable quantities, which is nonsensical.  For instance, if in one group $\lambda = 1$ and in another group $\lambda = -1,$ you would be comparing the mean of the first group to the mean reciprocal of the second group.   That's literally an "apples to oranges" kind of comparison.  cc @BenBolker

@whuber good point.
